# Meteor testing with mocha and meteor.methods

Tags: meteor, mocha.js, meteor-blaze

I am trying to figure out how to use Mocha Testing with Meteor. I found this tutorial: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/testing and I am getting this error at step "11.3  Prepare the database for each test":

> Error: Can't find npm module 'client/tasks.js'. Did you forget to call
>   'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?

I tried to adjust import path for my task.js file:

```
import { Tasks } from '../../client/tasks.js';
```

My project directory structure:

```
imports/api/tasks.tests.js
client/tasks.js
client/tasks.html
server/methods.js
mycollection.js
```

I don't use react, just blaze. I have meteor.methods for database/collection manipulation like "rename task", "create task" etc.

My tasks.js and tasks.html are in the client folder. From the client/tasks.js I am calling with Meteor.call() my Meteor.methods, for example:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
    'change .field': function(e) {
         var newName = e.target.value;
         Meteor.call('renameTask', this._id, newName);
    },
```

How can I transfer this tutorial to my example with Meteor.call? A small working example with Meteor.call() would help me a lot.

If it is relevant: Meteor is installed on Windows 10 System.

Comment: There is a Blaze tutorial version, it may help: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/testing

Comment: Blaze and React testing tutorials are identically. Different links with the same content.

Answer (score 0):

You can give relative path for you file like:

```
import { Tasks } from '../client/tasks.js';
```

Or an absolute path like:

```
import { Tasks } from '/client/tasks.js';
```

Please refer your directory structure and give a path accordingly.

Comment: I tried again and and moved this test file to the same path as in this tutorial: _imports/api/tasks.tests.js_ . My test file was in the project root directory before. Now I am trying to import my js-file again with `import { Tasks } from '../../client/tasks.js';` and I am getting the same error: _Error: Cannot find module '../../client/tasks.js'_ . I will update my question with my project folder structure.

Comment: Project directory structure added.

Comment: Files in the imports directory don't load unless imported fro outside of imports directory. Are you referring your test file from outside?

Comment: What do you mean with "outside" and how can I do it? I can't find it on the tutorial side. At my first try I put my test-file in the root project directory. Later moved it in the same directory as in the tutorial.

Comment: It here in the [docs](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories). But I don't think it should cause in issues while executing tests.